# wp_query to display custom taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization

I have a custom post type named 'tours' and custom taxonomy named 'tourtypes' so i can categorize it into terms like 'cultural tour', 'sports tour' etc.

I'm not the original author of this theme and don not know much about dealing with taxonomy. But I want to extend it so that instead of outputting all 'tours' post, user can also choose which tour category they want.

in the theme template taxonomy-tourtypes.php this is part of the code to display the term title which work:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'tourtypes'); foreach ($terms as $term){ ;?>
<h2><?php echo $term->name; ?> Category</h2><?php } ;?>
```

But when it comes to the part where i want to query the specified term it didnt work.

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_string_paged();
$counter = 1;
$termg = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'tourtypes', array("fields" => "all"));

$posts_per_page = get_option('theme_show_portfolio_items');
   if($posts_per_page == "") {
    $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
}

<?php
  $paged = get_query_string_paged();
  $counter = 1;
  $termg = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'tourtypes', array("fields" => "all"));

  $posts_per_page = get_option('theme_show_portfolio_items');
if($posts_per_page == "") {
    $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
}

  $my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'tours', 'tourtypes' =>'$termg'    ,'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page));
  ...
```

I manage to get it to work if i type in the term slug eg.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'tours', 'tourtypes' =>'cultural' ...
```

I'm sure i just need a little change on the wp_query.
Anyone care to point to the right code..i almost give up with this

Comment: If you are using the default [wp template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) (which it looks like you are) you won't need any special WP query, WordPress will just know. So take a standard loop. Make a backup of that template, then add a normal WP look and see how you get on. It should be what you want.

Comment: @Cristian Please add that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a custom taxonomy query add the 'tax_query' => array()

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'featured_job',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 9999999,
    'orderby' =>  'date',
    'order' => 'DES',

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_category', // custom taxonomy
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    =>  'business',    // taxonomy term (category)
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Moved comment to answer as suggested by @kaiser **

Original comment accepted as answer

> If you are using the default [wp template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) (which it
>   looks like you are) you won't need any special WP query, WordPress
>   will just know. So take a standard loop. Make a backup of that
>   template, then add a normal WP look and see how you get on. It should
>   be what you want.